# Monkeyrunner "drag" command uses incorrect coordinates? Is this a bug?

Tags: android, drag, monkeyrunner

I'm exploring the Monkeyrunner scripting environment, testing various events to make sure I can adequately simulate my app.  Specifically I have questions about the coordinates used in the "drag" function.

With Monkeyrunner connected but no app running (i.e., just sitting at the home screen), entering the following command will mimic a left-right "swipe" event, moving one home screen to the left.

```
device.drag((100,400),(500,400),0.15,5)
```

This works beautifully.

This command, then should produce a swipe in the opposite direction...

```
device.drag((500,400),(100,400),0.15,5)
```

...but it doesn't.

But this does:

```
device.drag((400,400),(100,400),0.15,5)
```

To further test this I downloaded the ["MagicMarker"](http://www.appbrain.com/app/magicmarker/com.jaytronix.markermagic) app.  This way I can see exactly where these different touch events are occurring.  Apparently it won't let me take a screenshot unless I'm using my own app, so I'll just have to describe what I'm seeing here.  Hopefully you can verify this or tell me what step I'm missing.

This command...

```
device.drag((100,400),(500,400),0.15,5)
```

...draws a horizontal line from left to right, across the middle of my screen.  It is exactly centered in my Motorola Droid's screen.  Both endpoints are clearly visible with a margin on either end.

This command...

```
device.drag((500,400),(100,400),0.15,5)
```

...which should be the same line drawn in the opposite direction (right to left), draws the line offset by 100px to the right.  The first endpoint is either at the edge of the screen or offscreen entirely.  I can't tell.

What's puzzling me is that the coordinates don't seem consistent.  The point (500,400) is in the vertical center of the screen and a bit off to the right if used as an endpoint in a left-right drag move, but seems to be offscreen entirely if used as a starting point in a right-left drag move.

It feels like this might be a bug in the Monkeyrunner environment.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 bugs here.  One in MonkeyRunner, the other in your code.  I'm testing on Nexus S, and the screen size is 480x800.  Driod is pretty close to that size  I checked it like this:

```
print device.getProperty('display.width'), device.getProperty('display.height')
```

So when you're dragging to the right, your last segment (at x=500) is off the edge of the screen.  When the framework gets that "up" event at the end of the drag, it seems to recover OK.

When you're dragging to the right, your first segment is off the screen, which the framework doesn't like.  Since it got a "down" event off-screen, it drops all the move events that complete the drag.

Doing you drags like this should work:

```
device.drag((100,400),(400,400),0.15,5)
time.sleep(0.5)
device.drag((400,400),(100,400),0.15,5)
```

The bug in MonkeyRunner is that it dropped the last section of your drag command.  So it looked like it was finishing the drag on the screen, but actually wasn't.  The fix to this is here: https://review.source.android.com/21635

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  I'm off to kick myself for not realizing what the resolution of my own screen was...